# Centralize vendor folder in Laravel 4.1.x

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, directory-structure

I wonder if is possibile to "move" the vendor folder to another location. I mean, I've a structure like this

- /
- Laravel Project 1
- Laravel Project 2
- Laravel Project 3
- [... others ...]
- CDN (For vendor if I can)

Well as you know every project comes with the vendor/ folder. I want to move that folder inside the CDN and "merge" all the requirements for every project in another composer outside the projects folder (inside CDN i guess).

**Why this?**

Simply because I've notice that vendors folder are nearly the same for every project so if I can combine all the "differences" in one single big vendor folder I can manage all the dependencies in one single location, pretty cool

Is that possible?

TY for any help :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel you can change the folder your applications load the framework and dependencies from `bootstrap/autoload.php`.

There's a `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` line in it and you can change it to whatever you need.
Thus you can change it to some outside folder, common to all projects.

Comment: Yup I see, and how about the composer part? How can I run a composer inside the CDN? just adding a single composer.json with all the require?

Comment: Yes, why not? Laravel does not depend on composer, it depends on the packages it maintains.

Comment: Ok, I'm doing it right now. If it's ok you'll take the point :)

Comment: There's a problem, My custom library inside "project1/app/lib/Project1" is hidden, IDK why. If I test another project, like project2, where there isn't any custom library it works like a charm

Comment: How are you including that library? I'm guessing a composer psr autoloader. You'll have to include it some other way or set up composer just for those (in each project you need to autoload libs) and include it's bootstrap.